# Como sobrepor dois conjuntos de div's utilizando CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, pessoal
Estou executando um pequeno projeto, trata-se de um jogo da memória. Minha ideia foi criar uma div (que é a carta) e dentro dessa div colocar outras duas divs (que são o front e o back da carta). Porém quando estilizo o front e o back não consigo fazer com que esses elementos fiquem sobrepostos.
O que eu queria fazer é deixar o front sobreposto ao back, assim quando o usuário clicar eu mudaria o display do front para 'none', assim a imagem apareceria.

O código fonte completo está aqui: https://github.com/NataliaCarvalho03/memoryGame.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi.

Fiz um jsfiddle usando o código que tens no repositório, podes ver aqui https://jsfiddle.net/Compay/4r1aqd1q/2/

Basicamente, a `div.card` tem de ter `position: relative;` e a `div.front` e `div.back` tem de ter `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`.
Isso fará com que ambas as faces fiquem no topo esquerdo da `div.card`, podes [ver aqui](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) mais info sobre esta técnica.

Em vez de esconder/mostrar as faces, o ideal é na `div.card` usares uma classe CSS para controlar qual face está visível, neste caso estou a usar a classe `.flipped`

Também coloquei uma pequena animação em CSS, baseada [neste artigo](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)

Espero que ajude um pouco, e te de motivação para continuar com o projecto. Caso tenhas mais duvidas, estaremos aqui para ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar dessa forma

```
<div id="carta">
<div id="back" style="display:block;"></div> 
<div id="front" style="display:none;"></div> 
</div> 

<button type="button" onclcick="virar()">Virar</button>

<script>
function virar(){
 $('#back').css("display", "none");
$('#front').css("display", "block");
}
<script>
```

Faz o teste ai. Nesse exemplo eu coloquei um Button que vira a carta, mas você pode fazer quando clicar sobre a Div principal.